# Как сделать приближение картинки автоматически?

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать так, чтобы картинка сама приближалась и отдалялась автоматически?

```css
.img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tapeciarnia.pl/tapety/normalne/tapeta-miejscowosc-santa-maddalena-w-polnocnych-wloszech.jpg" class="img" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.zoom {
  animation: zoom 25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  50% {
    transform: scale(2.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tapeciarnia.pl/tapety/normalne/tapeta-miejscowosc-santa-maddalena-w-polnocnych-wloszech.jpg" class="img zoom" />
```

Comment: Красота ))) Век живи век учись. Скопировал себе )))

Comment: Мне бы Ваши познания в css. ))) Если честно - будете смеяться, но в такой задаче я бы в первую очередь начал думать через js ))) Хотя всё гораздо проще оказалось.